# Position search bar at the right side of div and centered

Tags: html, css

I want to position a search bar inside a div so it looks something like this:

At the moment it doesn't even sit within the div.

[image]

HTML:

```css
.sb-search {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sb-search-input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 20px 65px 20px 20px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbar" style="position: relative;">
  <h1>Welcome Solictior...</h1>
  <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
    <form>
      <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Search..." type="text" value="" name="search" id="search" />
      <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="" />
      <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Flexbox` Can help.

Comment: Please provide a working plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to do with Flexbox

```
.searchbar {
  background-color: #8BCAC7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cb3fu9wj/

`justify-content` specifies the alignment along the main axis. It defines how the free space is distributed between elements.

`align-items` specifies the alignment along the cross axis.

Here's the [complete guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: I've tried using this and I am currently reading the flexbox guide, and the search box is positioned where i want it, however it displays like the [image i've linked here](http://imgur.com/a/RbOEa) The search box seems to span the entire width of the div?

Comment: fixed it! it was a simple padding issue ... thanks again sir kindly!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem here is the `h1` as it's a ***block level element***.

Add this to your `h1` CSS and it should let the search bar go to the right of it.

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Keep the `float: right;` on your `.sb-search` element too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible example of what you're looking for : [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3z9m2k06/3/)

**CSS :**

```
.searchbar { background-color: teal;  color: #fff; overflow: hidden; padding: 0 10px;}
.searchbar .sb-search { float: right; margin: 5px 0; }
.searchbar h1 { float: left; font-size: 14px; margin: 10px 0 5px; }
```

Comment: Thank you sir, sorry i'm very much a newbie